# Taking Samples from a Conditional Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, estimation

I am interested in knowing how to take samples from a conditional probability distribution.

Suppose I have the joint probability distribution for a bivariate normal distribution:

[image]

Suppose the mean vector for this bivariate normal distribution is mu = (5,10) and the covariance matrix (element_11, element_12, element_21, element_22) is (1,0.5,0.5,1). Using the R programming language, here is a visualization of this (R will generate many points from this specific bivariate normal distribution and then plot these points):

```
library("mvtnorm")
range = seq(-5, 5, 0.1)
mean = c(5, 10)
Sigma = matrix(c(1, .5, .5, 1), 2)
out = matrix (rep(0, 101*101), 101)

for (i in 1:length(range)){
    for (j in 1:length(range)){
        out[i,j] = dmvnorm(c(range[i], range[j]), mean=mean, 
                            sigma=Sigma)
    }
}
persp(out, theta = 30, phi = 30, col="lightblue")
```

[image]

**Problem:** I am interested in taking samples from this joint probability distribution and finding out the conditional distribution, e.g. P(X1 | X2 = 0.5).

**What I have tried so far:**

**1) Generating the conditional distribution based on the (convenient) theoretical properties of the multivariate Gaussian (i.e. normal) distribution**

There is a convenient theoretical property of multivariate gaussian distributions which easily allow us to move between the joint probability distribution and the conditional probability distribution :

[image]

So if I want to find out **"P(X1 | X2 = 0.5)"**: P(X1 | X2 = 0.5) itself has a normal distribution with mu = 5 + 0.5(0.5-10) and sigma = 1 - (0.5^2 / 1). Thus, using the theoretical properties of the multivariate Gaussian distribution, **P(X1 | X2 = 0.5) ~ N( mu = 0.25, sigma = 0.75)**.

In R, I can simulate this conditional distribution easily:

```
hist(rnorm(10000, 0.25, 0.75))
```

[image]

However, in the real world, we can not always rely on the convenient properties of the multivariate normal distribution - especially when we have high dimensional, irregular and non-normal distribution functions. This is why we use different MCMC (Markov Chain Monte Carlo) based approaches for taking samples from the conditional distribution, such as:

- Importance Sampling
- Acceptance-Rejection Sampling
- Gibb's Sampling
- Metropolis-Hastings

**My Question:** Assuming we know the joint probability distribution and have an expression for the conditional distribution, does anyone know any R packages (or ways in STAN) to take samples from this conditional distribution? I spent some time looking online, but there does not appear to be a straightforward way to do this. Suppose I take the same conditional distribution from above: **P(X1 | X2 = 0.5)** : Is it possible to take samples (with R) from this conditional distribution using any of the above sampling algorithms? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

****Note: **** I found a library in R ("AR" : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AR/index.html) which perform Acceptance-Rejection Sampling, but only on a limited number of distributions (e.g. not custom distributions). Below, I used this library to take samples from an Exponential Distribution (lambda = 2), with the Log Normal Distribution (mu = 0, variance = 1) as the candidate distribution:

```
library(AR)

f_X = function(x) dlnorm(x, 0, 1)
Sim <- AR.Sim(n=1000, f_X, Y.dist="exp", Y.dist.par=2 )
hist (Sim)
```

[image]

Comment: The statement "R will generate many points from this specific bivariate normal distribution and then plot these points" is incorrect wrt the bivariate plot. The density is simply computed on a regular grid and rendered by `persp`.

Comment: Without further details, the answer to the question is "yes, using a simulation algorithm like accept-reject, &tc., leads to simulating from the conditional expressed as proportional to the joint". But there is no R package that can operate on every distribution without the user's input.

Comment: @Xi'an : thank you for your reply! I will keep that in mind about the "persp" function

Comment: @Xi'an :  if you have time, could you please show me how to take the samples from the conditional distribution P(X1 | X2 = 0.5) using some sampling method in R (e.g. Acceptance-Rejection, Gibbs Sampling, Metropolis Hastings)? thank you so much!

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question actually is.  Do you have a bivariate Normal distribution, as the entire first 3/4 of your question including the **Problem:** and **What I have tried so far:** statements would indicate, or are you asking a more general question?

Comment: @jbowman: thank you for your reply! My question: i am trying to learn how to take sampling algorithms (e.g. acceptance rejection, gibbs sampling, metropolis Hasting) and take random samples from the bivariate normal distribution in my question. If you have time, can you please show me how to do this? Thank you!